# Why are squares appearing on my model in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I created a lighting scene in blender 2.8. with a plane as the background.
For now I hid my objects because they are not the problem here. And I also like the positions of the lights.

While rendering I noticed that you can see the squares of my model. Which is weird because I put on a subdivision surface modifier as well as Smooth Shade. 
I think it's because of my light settings, I don't know what to change though.

[image]

Blender file--> http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51823

Comment: The problem is with Area.001 Contact light Softness. I don't see the solution without decreasing of it.

Comment: @RUben thank you!!